# #include <sys/socket.h> in Visual Studio Linux console application not found

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, sockets

I get the error "cannot open source file sys/socket.h" when I try to add `#include <sys/socket.h>` to a new Visual Studio **Linux console** application.

How can I get Visual Studio to find this header file?

Comment: You should/may add the paths to the `sys` folder. For that you need to check the help pages of your VS console application

Comment: Debian, Ubuntu : `libc6-dev` provides `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h` .... Fedora, CentOS : `glibc-headers` provides `/usr/include/sys/socket.h`